# Give custom module's access to all in Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, acl

I have created a custom module for backend in Magento 1.9.

This module is applicable to all users and roles.

```
<menu>
    <videos module="videos">
        <title>Video Tutorials</title>
        <sort_order>900</sort_order>               
        <children>
            <bitsvideo module="videos">
                <title>BITS</title>
                <sort_order>5</sort_order>
                <action>videos/adminhtml_videos</action>
            </bitsvideo>
        </children>
    </videos>
</menu>
<acl>
    <resources>
        <admin>
            <children>
                <videos module="videos">
                    <sort_order>900</sort_order>               
                    <children>
                      <bitsvideo module="videos">
                          <title>BITS</title>
                          <sort_order>5</sort_order>
                          <action>videos/adminhtml_videos</action>
                       </bitsvideo>
                    </children>
                  </videos>  
            </children>
        </admin>
    </resources>
</acl>
```

How do I write `acl` for this?

The above code is my `acl`. What do I need to change?

How can I write acl to give permissions to all users by default?

Answer (score 2):

The ACL will be written in `app/code/local/{package}/{module}/etc/adminhtml.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config>
<menu>
    <videos module="videos" translate="title">
        <title>Video Tutorials</title>
        <sort_order>900</sort_order>               
        <children>
            <bitsvideo module="videos" translate="title">
                <title>BITS</title>
                <sort_order>5</sort_order>
                <action>videos/adminhtml_videos</action>
            </bitsvideo>
        </children>
    </videos>
</menu>
<acl>
    <resources>
        <all>
            <title>Allow Everything</title>
        </all>
        <admin>
            <children>
                <videos module="videos" translate="title">
                    <title>Video Tutorials</title>
                    <sort_order>900</sort_order>               
                    <children>
                        <bitsvideo module="videos" translate="title">
                            <title>BITS</title>
                            <sort_order>5</sort_order> //dont need action tag bellow
                        </bitsvideo>
                    </children>
                </videos>  
            </children>
        </admin>
    </resources>
</acl>
</config>
```

You can set the acl config in  : `System > Permissions > Roles`

Comment: I have 70 roles in my magento. I can not give permission by open `System > Permissions > Roles` to 70 roles,It will not be efficient.

Comment: Yes, i understand but you have to do it manually

Comment: Really.? no other way @Prince.?

Comment: No, sorry. they will be checked by default only for roles who have `all permissions`